# Using markdown loader in vue, rendering speciall characters differently in prod and dev

Tags: vue.js, markdown, netlify, showdown

I'm using Vue on netlify and it's rendering special characterss differently in prod and dev:
I'm using markdown-loader and vue showdown load the content from my md files.
But they are rendering differently on localhost (Windows) and in prod (netlify)
when I run on localhost my codeblocks render like this:

```
{
    "bucket_name": "gtm-state",
    "blob_name": "state.json",
    "gtm_containers": ["32154678_156753"],
    "slack_hook": "https://my.slack.hook.com",
    "microsoft_hook": "https://my.microsoft.hook.com",
    "cloud_credetials": "mycredentials.json"
}
```

but in prod i get this result:

```
{
    &quot;bucket_name&quot;: &quot;gtm-state&quot;,
    &quot;blob_name&quot;: &quot;state.json&quot;,
    &quot;gtm_containers&quot;: [&quot;32154678_156753&quot;],
    &quot;slack_hook&quot;: &quot;https://my.slack.hook.com&quot;,
    &quot;microsoft_hook&quot;: &quot;https://my.microsoft.hook.com&quot;,
    &quot;cloud_credetials&quot;: &quot;mycredentials.json&quot;
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you running the _exact_ same code in both places? Are you running the code exactly the same way? Same build process, same configuration, etc.?

Comment: Its deployed from The same branch on github. I guess The difference is the dev version is on Windows. And netlify is probably on linux